# Sketching a nice graph of $f(x) = x^2 + 2x – 8$

Tags: calculus, education

I would like to sketch a nice graph of $$f(x) = x^2 + 2x – 8$$

including labeling the coordinates of the vertex and intercepts.

I tried to graph it using [this](http://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/) tool:

[image: base graph]

But I don't know how to label the coordinates of the vertex and intercepts.

Please help.

Comment: Which tool / software do you use for graphing it?

Comment: this : rechneronline.de/function-graphs

Comment: First you can sketch the graph by hand. I think this is the Intention of this exercise. Second you can print out the graph and enter the missing information.

Comment: What do you need this graph sketched for? Maybe there are better programs?

Comment: I recommend http://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: Are you asking about sketching by yourself or you are asking to use the software / graphing tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using [this site](http://www.mathportal.org/calculators/quadratic-equation/quadratic-function-grapher.php), which only currently graphs quadratic functions.

This is what I got on the site above
[image: This is what I got]
Another alternative seems to use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2B2x-8%20intercept)
but it does not show the vertex in the same graph as the intercepts (well I couldn't manage to make it do so)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

I think if you mess around with these options you'll have better luck

[image]

Comment: please can you use another program to graph the function

Comment: I can think of at least 10 programs that can accomplish your task. Can you help narrow it down to things your comfortable with?

Comment: This website should be perfectly fine--you can save the plot once you've adjusted the plotting window & use, say, paint, to add the vertices/intercepts/what have you.

Comment: also, please let us know if you're just struggling with _plotting_ the items of interest, or whether you're struggling as well with _calculating_ them.

Answer (score 2):

So the intercepts first.

When $x=0$ you have $f(x)=-8$ so the point $(0,-8)$ is on the graph.

When $f(x)=0$ you have $x^2+2x-8=0$ and you can see from the graph you have, or from solving the quadratic, or by factoring as $(x+4)(x-2)=0$ that this happens at the points $(-4,0)$ and $(2,0)$.

The vertex is the maximum or minimum point - now this can be done using calculus, but completing the square is as easy for a quadratic. I'll leave you to see whether you can identify the relevant point, and determine whether it is a maximum or minimum, if the function is rewritten $f(x)=(x+1)^2-9$.

That gives you four key points, and together with the knowledge that the graph is a parabola, you should be able to construct a decent sketch.

Comment: I believe they were looking for software help, not sketching the graph by hand.

Comment: @Sky If the problem is about software then he must have clearly written it. If he hasn't written it clearly then its his fault not of sir Mark Bennet.

Comment: @Singh I was only notifying him; I wasn't ascribing fault to anyone.

Comment: @Sky I took it that way in the end from comments, but left the answer up so that other people who had curve-sketching problems might see it - if they came this way.

Comment: @Sky Sir sorry if my comment was rude. There was an answer to this problem  which got -5 and finally it was closed. That answer was correct but then too it was closed. This was the reason behind my frustration. I'm sorry.